# Google map won't load

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Map wont load on my website 'till browser window is resized

Here is my JS code

```
<div class="map-cont">
        <div id="map" class="location-container map-padding" style="width:100%;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>
          <script>
          function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: 45.4420432, lng: 15.999982};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 15,
              center: uluru,
              scrollwheel: false
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEQc2mBnThiUz-Pj472iG1i2FyqJvNb00&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </div>
```

And here is CSS

```
#map { width: 100% !important; }
.map-cont { margin-left: 10%; }
```

When I remove `.map-cont { margin-left: 10%; }` it works fine, but I don't need it fullscreen.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/38ueLsh4/ a me sembra funzioni

Comment: the code in the fiddle (also here https://jsfiddle.net/jqxL8dhu/) is exactly what you've shown us and it works. So must be something to do with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adjusting the css and include these lines lines.

```
   #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   html,body{
     height: 100%;
     margin:0px;
   }
```

The google maps api wants to explicitly define the height and width of the map, and at times this can cause complications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the sizing issue was that the

```
      style="width:100%;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>
      <script>
```